# Excel: Sumproduct, input of array and range not working

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, range

I am trying to do a sumproduct such as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1})
```

but it give #VALUE! error,

While it is gives a valid value for

```
=SUMPRODUCT({8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1},{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1})
```

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,A1:A8)
```

According to my understanding it only works if all inputs are of Range or Array type, but not when there are both. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(D3:D10),{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1})
```

> EDIT: Above code **works** if entered as array forumla

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D10,TRANSPOSE({8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}))
```

works without entering as array formula.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `;` for vertical array :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,{8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1})
```

`{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}` is horizontal array similar to horizontal range like  `A1:H1` which will not work well with the vertical range `A1:A8`

---

I can't test it, but another way can be with the `Row` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,9-Row(A1:A8))
```